# Is there a way to get a count about grouped rows?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get a count about a grouped rows. Here is a description of the table of relevance:

```
column_name     data_type
-------------   ---------
id              integer
title           character varying
release_year    integer
country         character varying
duration        integer
language        character varying
certification   character varying
gross           bigint
budget          bigint
```

I am to trying to determine how many different years exist during which more than 200 movies were released.

Here is the query I have tried so far:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT release_year)
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 200;
```

...which gives *13* rows of `1s`.

The question is: how to get a number *13*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `GROUP BY release_year` but you count release years so you will get 1s, nothing else. If you want to count them, you can enclose in a derived table and do another aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS release_years_with_200_titles
FROM
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM films
    GROUP BY release_year
    HAVING COUNT(title) > 200
  ) AS dt ;
```

It can be done without a derived table but it's not very clear how it works:

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(*) OVER () AS release_years_with_200_titles
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(title) > 200
LIMIT 1 ;
```

The `COUNT(*) OVER ()` will count the number of rows (after the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`). We then can use `SELECT DISTINCT` or even better `LIMIT 1` to get a single `13` in the result and not thirteen rows with `13`.